# How to print the path alias without "/" in views

Tags: views, path-aliases

I would like to print the path of a node in a view, but without the "/".

With "Content:path" the trailing slash before the alias is always there.

ie:

```
path-of-node
```

in stead of 
`/path-of-node`
Any suggestions, pls?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom module of your own, you can use the function below.
To find the exact structure of the data you want to modify, you can use dpm or just simply print_r.

```
function hook_views_pre_render(&$view) {
    if($view->name == "MY_VIEW"){
        foreach($view->result as $key => $r){
           $view->result[$key]->path[0]["rendered"]["#markup"] = substr($view->result[$key]->path[0]["rendered"]["#markup"], 0, -1); 
    } //if
 } // function
```

As for a direct way, I was trying and I think I even post a question, but to no success. Surely it is much simpler but don't know how to.